# Event when ScrollController get attached

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to display a widget once I have info about the max scroll extent. I can find that number if I assign an instance of `ScrollController` to the `controller` property of a scrollable widget.

My problem is that the `ScrollController` gets attached to the scrollable widget during the build, so I can not use the max scroll extent number before the first build. Thus what I was trying to do is display an empty `Container` in the first build and then switch that empty `Container` with the widget I actually want. Something like this:

```
    _scrollController.positions.length == 0 ? new Container() : new Align(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: new Container(
        width: constraints.maxWidth,
        height: 50.0,
        color: Colors.black,
      )
    )
```

Now this does not work of course because `_scrollController.positions.length` will be 0 at the beginning and nowhere do I call `setState` when this value changes (when the controller gets attached).
**So my question:** Is there a place where I can get notified whenever the `ScrollController` gets attached to a scrollable widget? Or is there a better approach for this?

Comment: Why do you need this info during build ? You will never be able to. As `build` reset `ScrollController.positions`.

Comment: @RémiRousselet I want to display some sort of shadow at the bottom of the screen ONLY if the view can be scrolled down. So I need to know the current scroll position and the max scroll extent to check this I believe.

Comment: You could do that with a custom sliver inside a `CustomScrollView`. Slivers aren't necesseraly scrolling. `SliverAppBar` is a perfect example. It even has the notion of having a shadow or not depending on scroll.

Comment: @RémiRousselet I'll have a deeper look into custom slivers tomorrow. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @RémiRousselet I took a look at the `SliverAppBar` implementation and the other slivers associated with it. It looks very complicated compared to what I was trying to do. I guess I don't fully understand where the sliver is going to get its extent when building the shadow. How can it do that when not everything completed building?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the scrollable is `widget.child`.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
    onNotification: _handleScrollNotification,
    child: widget.child,
  );
}

bool _handleScrollNotification(ScrollNotification notification) {
  if (notification is ScrollUpdateNotification || notification is OverscrollNotification) {
    widget.child.update(notification.metrics);
  }
return false;
}

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => afterFirstLayout(context));
}

void afterFirstLayout(BuildContext context) {
  applyInitialScrollPosition();
}

void applyInitialScrollPosition() {
  ScrollController scrollControler = widget.child.controller;
  ScrollPosition position = scrollControler.position;
  ScrollNotification notification = ScrollUpdateNotification(
      metrics: FixedScrollMetrics(
          minScrollExtent: position.minScrollExtent,
          maxScrollExtent: position.maxScrollExtent,
          pixels: position.pixels,
          viewportDimension: position.viewportDimension,
          axisDirection: position.axisDirection),
      context: null,
      scrollDelta: 0.0);
_handleScrollNotification(notification);
}
```

The child must `extends ChangeNotifier` and has an `update` method:

```
void update(ScrollMetrics metrics) {
  assert(metrics != null);
  _lastMetrics = metrics; // Save the metrics.
  notifyListeners();
}
```

All this only works if a scroll controller has explicitly been defined for the scrollable (widget.child).