# How to create a scroll indicator

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to display a shadow/scroll indicator at the bottom of a `CustomScrollView` to indicate that the user can scroll down. The scroll indicator should only be visible when you can in fact scroll down.

- In my first attempt to create this, I assigned a `ScrollController`
  to the `CustomScrollView` so that I can get the maximum scroll extent and
  the current scroll position. This didn't work unfortunately because
  the `ScrollController` only gets attached to the `CustomScrollView`
  during first build, so I can not use it during the first build to get
  the info I need.
- For my second attempt, I took a closer look at implementing a custom
  `Sliver`, but without any luck. I tried getting some inspiration from
  the `SliverAppBar` code (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49660921/event-when-scrollcontroller-get-attached?noredirect=1#comment86332212_49660921)) but found that it
  was pretty difficult to understand and that there isn't a lot of info
  about `Sliver`s out yet.

**My question:** How could I implement this (without custom slivers if possible)? If slivers are needed, I'd love to get some additional info and perhaps some links to resources covering this topic.

Comment: Maybe you want to look at `Scrollbar` too.

Comment: @RémiRousselet From what I understand, it uses a `NotificationListener` with a `ScrollNotification` generic to pick up the scroll events. So I believe it actually does not give any info about whether there is room to scroll down, it just notifies of changes when the user actually scrolls. Also, this listener will also be attached at the first build so I believe I'd have the same issue as with my first attempt :/

Comment: @RémiRousselet This might also be an issue with using a `ScrollNotification`:

- When a scroll notification is received by a NotificationListener, the listener will have already completed build and layout, and it is therefore too late for that widget to call State.setState. (https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ScrollNotification-class.html)

Comment: Yeah right. Than Slivers are the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to detect when the user has scrolled down to the bottom of the ListView, you can set a ScrollController listener if the scroll position is at the edge.

```dart
_scrollController.addListener(() {
  if (_scrollController.position.atEdge) {
    if (_scrollController.position.pixels == 0) {
      debugPrint('Scroll position at top');
    } else {
      debugPrint('Scroll position at bottom');
      // Load more list items
    }
  }
});
```

Remember that the ScrollController needs to be configured on the ListView.

```dart
ListView.builder(
  controller: _scrollController,
  ...
)
```