# How to add scroll indicator in ListView

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, scrollview, flutter-widget

Is there any way to show the scroll indicator on the `ListView`?

Here is my basic code:

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: 50,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(title: Text("Item= ${index + 1}"),),
)
```

Comment: May be helpful for you:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49675720/how-to-create-a-scroll-indicator

Comment: You need to ensure the ListView is actually smaller than it's content, otherwise it won't show a scrollbar. If you put ListView into a scrollable there won't be a scrollbar because it has infinite size.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I am using 50 elements and only 10 are visible at the same time on the screen so `ListView` is smaller than it's content and which is why it scrolls, I thought there would be some inbuilt indicator attached with the ListView but there was nothing like that.

Comment: I expected so as well. If not just wrap it in a Scrollbar https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Scrollbar-class.html

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer it worked. I answered my own question, if you want I can delete it and you can write it and i will accept and upvote it.

Answer (score 205, accepted):

Thanks to [Günter Zöchbauer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/217408/g%C3%BCnter-z%C3%B6chbauer).

You can wrap your `ListView` in `Scrollbar`

```
Scrollbar(
    child: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: 50,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(title: Text("Item= ${index + 1}"),),),
)
```

Comment: Based on my Android knowledge I'm wondering if you are not now rendering all elements and putting everything in a Scrollbar

Comment: If you remove itemCount: 50, the list will be infinity and by default, the scroll should not be here

Comment: In a list of 500 items, where 37 are visible, it renders only 50 items (which is good).

Comment: Note that this solution (to wrap in `Scrollbar`) **applies to any scrollable widget** (for example  `SingleChildScrollView`), not only to ListView. Set the **`isAlwaysShown`** param to true so that the scrollbar is visible even when not scrolling; however even if isAlwaysShown is true if there is no need for a scrollbar (because the scrollable content does not exceed its limits) the scrollbar will not be displayed.

Comment: You should mention that you need a ScrollController. At least MY ListView + Scrollbar didn't work without controller.

Answer (score 20):

I think better to use `CupertinoScrollbar` instead of `Scrollbar`. With `CupertinoScrollbar`, you can grab the scrollbar to move around in the list with it, whereas `Scrollbar` is just a visual cue and you cannot interact with the scrollbar directly.

**Ex:**

```
 CupertinoScrollbar(
            child: ListView.builder(...),
```

**Or**

```
Scrollbar(
    child: ListView.builder(...),
```

Comment: I would claim every element of flutter "can touch" and every Scrollbar can scroll to the bottom if the list is finite. Could you elaborate on what you really mean? I'm only testing as Windows application and don't see much difference.

Comment: I dont know why, but cuppertinoScrollBar really do the trick. It just make Listview and Scrollbar work in same direction.

Answer (score 8):

You can implement this **designer** scrollbar library :

1. [draggable_scrollbar](https://pub.dev/packages/draggable_scrollbar)
2. [alphabet scrolling](https://pub.dev/packages/alphabet_list_scroll_view)

OR

You can wrap ListView in `Scrollbar` widget

```
Scrollbar(
    child: ListView.builder(...),
)
```

Comment: The indication of the two external packages is very useful. In Flutter it is more important than in other frameworks the integration with external dependencies.

Answer (score 8):

Create a ScrollController variable `(ScrollController _scrollController);`
Instatiate `_scrollController` inside `initState()` or wherever you want, `_scrollController = ScrollController();`
Add `_scrollController` variable inside `Scrollbar` and `ListView` properties,

```
controller:_scrollController
```

Here's the code:

```
ScrollController _scrollController;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _scrollController = ScrollController();
  }
Scrollbar(
        isAlwaysShown: true,
         controller: _scrollController,
         child: ListView(
         controller: _scrollController,
   )
```

if you don't want it always shown set to false

```
thumbVisibility: false,
```

Comment: This works better if you need the scroll bar to be visible right from the start, which is what I was looking for in my case. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 4):

```
Scrollbar(
        thickness: 10,
        isAlwaysShown: true,
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: _controller().transactonsList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Card(
              elevation: 5,
              child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16),
                height: 80,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(width: 10),
                    amountOfTransaction(index),
                    SizedBox(width: 16),
                    dateAndTitleOfTransaction(index),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      )
```

Comment: "_controller().transactonsList.length"? "amountOfTransaction"? Where do you conjure all this stuff from?

Answer (score 0):

```
final ScrollController _scroll = ScrollController();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  (...)
  child: ListView.builder(
    controller: _scroll,
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If u need to style your scroll bar a bit wrap the **ListView** in **RawScrollbar** and **use the same scroll controller instance** for both widgets

```
final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      (...)
      child: RawScrollbar(
          controller: _scrollController,
          thumbColor: Colors.redAccent,
          radius: const Radius.circular(8),
          crossAxisMargin: 2,
          child: ListView.builder(
            controller: _scrollController,
            itemCount: 50,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
              title: Text("Item= ${index + 1}"),
            ),
          ),
        ),
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Scrollbar(
child:ListView.builder(
itemCount:20,
itemBuilder:(c,i)  =>  MyItem(i),
),
),

*You have to give itemcount as how many list you have*
-----**Example:  itemCount: items.length,**-----

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can also tune this scrollbar with ScrollbarTheme.

```
            Container(
                constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 200),
                child: ScrollbarTheme(
                  data: const ScrollbarThemeData(
                    crossAxisMargin: -8,
                    thickness: MaterialStatePropertyAll(4.0),
                    thumbColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.red),
                  ),
                  child: Scrollbar(
                    child: ListView.separated(
                      ...
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```