# Any ways to custom scrollbar indicator height in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm finding a way to custom my scrollbar indicator height.

Please help if you have a solution.

Comment: Scrolling thumb height depends on currently visible position inside ScrollView. The longer ScrollView content height is, the shorter thumb height will be. You can't set it manually, moreover I don't see any reason to do it.

Comment: its the same case with this [customscrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53030672/flutter-how-to-add-scroll-indicator-in-listview)

Comment: @Mol0ko What if designers require this? Why are you denying the motivation for this question? I need this, because it is specifically required in my current design document. I'll try to make a workaround and post it here. My idea is to create two `ScrollControllers` that manipulate each other, but are displayed in different Widgets.