# how to make this Flutter Page slide indicator?

Tags: flutter

[image]

Anyone can help me, i want to know - what is name of this indicator.
How can I make this flutter page slide indicator in flutter.

If any packages to build it, please share the packages.

Thanks.

Comment: You can search for scroll indicators (or vertical scroll indicator). Also please these these link if they are of any help - [scroll indicator list view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53030672/flutter-how-to-add-scroll-indicator-in-listview) ,  [scrollbar indicators](https://flutter-examples.com/show-scrollbar-indicator-in-scrollview-in-flutter/) , [draggable scrollbar](https://pub.dev/packages/draggable_scrollbar)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your ListView in a [ScrollBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scrollbar-class.html) widget. You'll be able to customize it (turn the color to yellow as your thumbnail shows) only on Android, because ScrollBar is hardcoded on iOS, it's the standard one. To do so, specify a ScrollBar theme as shown in this [article1](https://www.kindacode.com/article/flutter-scrollbar/).

Another way to do it would be to implement your own ScrollBar widget, so it will look the same on both platforms : [article2](https://habr.com/en/post/574296/) (of course it needs some adjustments but it's a good start)

I hope it can help and have a nice day !

Answer (score 0):

I would use a flutter widget called `PageView`.

And there will be **2 containers** nested inside each other.

- Outer Container will have a transparent background.
- Inner Container will be the View you wanna show.

You probably want to adjust the `size` and `scrollDirection` of the Page.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html